# How do I use toLocaleDateString() and .toLocaleTimeString() to add to my log-file name?

Tags: javascript, string, time, logfile

I just trying to save the log file in CSV format with a time stamp in the filename at the end, e.g.: `File_YYYMMDD_HHmmSS`.

How can I make it with a date with `toLocaleDateString()` and `toLocaleDateString()`. I could export log-file with `LocaleDateString()` in format like: `Logfile_21.8.2023`

But if it comes to Time, it has ":" between hours and minutes and seconds (e.g.:05:15:30 PM). Can you give me some advice? I need to extract the date and time and add it to the filename as of the time of export of `.csv` log archive.

Comment: Remove the `:`?